# Integrating React Native Firebase into existing iOS app with Firebase

Tags: react-native-firebase

We are currently a brownfield iOS app (with parts of the app in React Native in v0.61).

If we are already integrating Firebase Crashlytics/Analytics natively via Cocoapods, how would we go about integrating RN Firebase for the React Native side?

Do we need to remove the existing pods and follow https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/app/ios instead?

Answer (score 0):

When integrating RN Firebase (invertase.io, v6, [iOS manual installation](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/analytics/ios)) into our brownfield iOS app that already has existing Firebase instance setup and operational, I removed the existing pod (`pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> x.xx.xx'`).
And installed the RNFirebase pod (`pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'`).

After installation, the native iOS setup we had before worked as is.